# Youtube video embedding thumbnail

Tags: youtube, embed

I have a youtube video playlist of 15 videos.

On my website when someone clicks a link, I am displaying a specific video within the playlist (example: video 5 of 15). My issue is that since YouTube no longer allows autoplay if you have the audio on, the video will display properly on the page, but it always shows the thumbnail of the first video in the playlist (not the thumbnail of video 5 in this example) which confuses the viewer because they think they are looking at the wrong video and therefore don't press the play button.

Does anyone know what I can do to make the correct thumbnail to show?

Note: I don't want to embed only video 5 (in this example) because I want video 6 to start playing automatically once video 5 completes.

Comment: can you help to provide your sample code, so we can help to understand your problem better. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response - here is what the embed code is displaying when showing video 5 (as an example - im using the "index=" parameter to designate what video in the playlist to play

Comment: <style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe id="youtube" src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLWG2N1BWudGIVg3fT1hJ_F6UeI1CjlH5D&index=5&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&fs=0'></iframe></div>